# Devo evitar conexões permanentes e classe Singleton em um projeto PHP

Tags: php, mvc, singleton

Estou desenvolvendo um CMS com PHP e utilizando o padrão MVC, sem utilizar frameworks, *eu sei que muitos vão dizer que eu não devo fazer isso, porém estou fazendo isso como uma forma de estudo.*

Porém, nunca compreendi muito bem alguns conceitos, como por exemplo o funcionamento das conexões permanentes. Pensei que haveria ganho de desempenho ao utilizar uma classe Singleton com uma conexão permanente ao meu banco de dados, aparentemente eu estava errado e encontrei muitos tópicos aqui no StackOverflow que recomendam **evitar a utilização desse padrão**, justamente por criar dependências em outras classes.

Então me surgiu a dúvida, como eu poderia ter uma conexão permanente à um banco de dados sendo que teria que *injetar* minha conexão por parâmetros para algum model sempre que eu precisar? Isso não iria instanciar um novo objeto e consecutivamente criar uma nova conexão?

Edit: Minha conexão é feita através de uma classe que estende a biblioteca PDO.

Comment: Por mais perguntas que faças, e a cada resposta que recebas, nao vais conseguir entender ao certo onde e quando se devem utilizar, por isso recomendo que experimentes antes, e só depois questiona. Isto porque, mesmo que alguém te explique e te dê um exemplo agora, é bem provável que continues sem resposta, isto porque esse tipo de padrão é tanto único quanto comum dependendo da situação.

Comment: O meu medo é apenas usar isso e se arrepender mais pra frente..

Comment: _"porém estou fazendo isso como uma forma de estudo"_ - É este o melhor momento para testes, do que funciona e como funciona e quais os contras do uso desse padrão nesse app. E utilizando o DI, terias que reescrever uma parte considerável do teu script.

Comment: O código em sí está bem pequeno, estou tentando fazer com baixo acoplamento, então acredito que não terei tanto trabalho. Mas vendo que o Singleton não funciona da forma que eu esperava, já meio que abandonei ele. Não quero que minhas views tenham acesso ao meu banco de dados, entende? Nesse caso prefiro algo mais encapsulado.

Comment: _"Mas vendo que o Singleton não funciona da forma que eu esperava"_ - Não é para funcionar da forma que esperas, ele vai funcionar da forma como ele funciona, é isso que fazem os padrões, são usados para resolver problemas específicos, mesmo muito específicos que o programador encontra durante a construção do projecto. São uma espécie de lógica compacta, não são propriamente aplicáveis em qualquer situação. Falas de _"conexão permanente"_, e referes *CMS*, mas citas um padrão que possui outras responsabilidades. É basicamente disto que falo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, acontece que os *"padrões não são de uso obrigatório"*, ou seja, não são regra para nada, não passam de uma solução para problemas comuns encontrados durante o desenvolvimento de um projecto. São como ferramentas que devemos usar apenas quando necessárias, e não quando achamos necessárias ou mesmo por acharmos que as devemos usar.

Injectar uma conexão numa classe, é o mesmo que injectar uma instância de conexão numa classe. E segundo o wikipédia ...

> **Injeção de dependência** (Dependency Injection, em inglês) é um padrão de desenvolvimento de programas de computadores utilizado quando é necessário manter baixo o nível de acoplamento entre diferentes módulos de um sistema. Nesta solução as dependências entre os módulos não são definidas programaticamente, mas sim pela configuração de uma infraestrutura de software (container) que é responsável por "injetar" em cada componente suas dependências declaradas. A Injeção de dependência se relaciona com o padrão Inversão de controle mas não pode ser considerada um sinônimo deste. É também directamente associada a **IoC** como mencionado anteriormente e **strategy patterns**. [«1»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Uma dependência pode ser vista como um serviço consumível, e uma injecção como um serviço consumido.

> **Exemplo:** Para utilizar os serviços de determinada operadora, colocamos um chip dessa mesma operadora no telemovel e esse telemóvel fornece a rede **e** os serviços, e nós consumimos estes serviços sejam quais forem, dependendo do chip usado. Nesse caso teríamos o telemóvel como container, responsável por introduzir esses serviços ao utilizador.

Como qualquer outro padrão de projecto, estes não fogem a lógica, se usados quando desnecessários tornam-se um incomodo, o código torna-se demasiado complexo à custa de nada e sabe-se lá quais outros problemas podem vir a causar. E pelo que vejo é claramente isto que vai acontecer contigo. Ao optares por estender a classe **PDO** em vez de iniciar uma instância num construtor como é comum, vê-se claramente que querias algo simples, e um *CMS* é basicamente um aplicação voltada ao **CRUD** e outras operações básicas. Acho que se usares uma classe de conexão normal não haverá qualquer complicação.

Uma coisa é querer aprender e outra é usar desnecessariamente. Por mim, se quiseres aprender a trabalhar com patterns, recomendo que procures algo mais focado à patterns para trabalhar, em vez de investir recursos desnecessários em algo que podes fazer à custa de nada, se é que me entendes.

## Quando são convenientes ?

- Você precisa injetar dados de configuração em um ou mais componentes.
- Você precisa injetar a mesma dependência em vários componentes.
- Você precisa injetar diferentes implementações da mesma dependência.
- Você precisa injetar a mesma implementação em diferentes configurações.
- Você precisa de alguns dos serviços prestados pelo container.

Sem mais delongas, acho que é hora de passar à alguns exemplos de uso, mas se quiseres aprofundar mais acerca de injecções, e também saber quais desvantagens possuem, ou mesmo pontos por mim **omitidos**, recomendo que leias estes artigos:

- [DI is EVIL (é apenas título, o conteúdo é realmente interessante)](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/dependency-injection-is-evil.html)
- [When isn't appropriate to use DI](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135971/when-is-it-not-appropriate-to-use-the-dependency-injection-pattern)
- [DI (muito explicativo)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)
- [When to use DI](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/dependency-injection/when-to-use-dependency-injection.html)
- [Unit Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)

Ou podes simplesmente usar o ***Google*** para mais resultados. Ainda, se achares pouco esclarecedor, analisa o código de um [framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Dependency_injection_frameworks) qualquer que possua algum destes padrões implementado, assim podes ver como são aplicados em produção.

## Exemplo sem Injecção:

```
<?php
#classe de conexão que estende a classe PDO
class Database extends PDO
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        # @Configuracao
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exemplo;charset=utf8;';
        $param = array('dsn'=>$dsn, 'user'=>'root', 'pwd'=>'');

        if(!empty($param)){
            try{
                parent::__construct($param['dsn'], $param['user'], $param['pwd']);
            } catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public function select($tabela, $args=null){
        if(!empty($tabela)){
            if(!empty($args)){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$tabela} WHERE {$args[0]} {$args[1]} {$args[1]}";
            } else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$tabela}";
            }
            if($this->data = parent::query($sql)){
                return $this->data;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

Classe que consumidora da **conexão**

```
<?php

require_once 'class.database.php';

class Books
{
    private $_db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_db = new Database();
    }

    public function fetchAll($tabela)
    {
        if($query = $this->_db->select($tabela)){
            if($resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
            return $resultado;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$instancia = new Books();
$livros = $instancia->fetchAll('exemplo');
foreach($livros as $livro){
    print "ID: #" . $livro->id . "<br/>";
    print "Titulo: " . $livro->titulo . "<br/>";
}

?>
```

## Exemplo com injecção:

```
<?php

include_once 'class.container.php';

class Books
{
    private $_db;
    // Construtor
    public function __construct(Container $param)
    {
        $this->_db = $param->Connect();
    }

    // Método que faz uso dessa instancia
    public function getAll($tabela)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$tabela}";
        if($query = $this->_db->query($sql)){
            while($resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                return $resultado;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

# @Books exemplo
# @Configuração:
$param = array('dsn'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exemplo;charset=utf8;',
               'user'=>'root',
               'pwd'=>'');
# Injecção do @Container na classe @Books              
$livros = new Books(new Container($param));

# Retornar os resultados da tabela @exemplo
$resultados = $livros->getAll('exemplo');
foreach($resultados as $resultado){
    print $resultado->titulo . "<br/>";
}

?>
```

Este seria o **container**, utilizando um **construtor**.

```
<?php

class Container
{
    private $instancia, $params;

    public function __construct($params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }
    public function Connect()
    {
        if(empty($this->instancia['db']))
        {
            $this->instancia['db'] = new PDO($this->params['dsn'], 
                                             $this->params['user'], 
                                             $this->params['pwd']
                                             );
        }
        return $this->instancia['db'];
    }
}

?>
```

Estes exemplos passados, são implementações muito simples desse padrão, normalmente criam-se rotas mais complexas para que funcionem de forma mais deliberada com diferentes configurações nas mais variadas situações. Essas configurações que aí estão, são algo que quase não se vê numa implementação mais aprofundada do padrão.

No final, não sei se terei cometido um ou alguns erros algures, mas é isto aí, a mais integra resposta que pude dar.

Answer (score 0):

se estas a utilizar o padrão MVC recomendo que crie um abstract model que será estendido por todas os outros modelos. Nesse seu modelo abstrato você pode implementar métodos como abrir conexão, fechar conexão, executar query, recuperar resultados, iniciar, vomitar e rollback de transações.

Assim todos os seus modelos terão acesso ao banco.

PS.: a forma como vai fazer a conexão é muito inerente a arquitetura que você deseja utilizar. Bom, essa é minha opinião.