# Padrão Singleton causa erro: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, singleton

Fiz esse padrão de Singleton que vi num site e achei ótimo, bem o que queria.
Contudo algo está dando errado pois tenho o erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myschool/DAO/Conncetion.php:37
Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/myschool/Login.php(18):DAO\Connection::getInstance() #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/myschool/login.php(5):Login->loginconnect() #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myschool
/DAO/Conncetion.php on line 37
```

E se eu coloco     function __construct() {} como privado ou protected ai sim para por esse motivo.
Já li sobre o uso do $this num contexto onde não é um objeto. Contudo eu quero usar esse comando por causa da ideia de carregar as váriaveis dinamicamente pelas funções.

Essa é a classe:

```
class Connection
{
    public static $instance;
    private static $dbtype   = "mysql";
    private static $host     = "localhost";
    private static $port     = "3306";
    private static $user     = "root";
    private static $password = "";
    private static $db       = "school";

    /*Metodos que trazem o conteudo da variavel desejada
     @return   $xxx = conteudo da variavel solicitada*/
    private static function getDBType()  {return self::$dbtype;}
    private static function getHost()    {return self::$host;}
    private static function getPort()    {return self::$port;}
    private static function getUser()    {return self::$user;}
    private static function getPassword(){return self::$password;}
    private static function getDB()      {return self::$db;}

     function __construct() {

    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {

     if(!isset(self::$instance)){
         self::$instance = new PDO($this->getDBType().":host=".$this->getHost().";port=".$this->getPort().";dbname=".$this->getDB(), $this->getUser(), $this->getPassword());
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);

        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __clone()
    {
    }
    private function __wakeup()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getInstance()` é **estático** logo não possui nenhuma referencia (ou não pode acessar) a atributos de um **objeto** então não é possível usar o `$this`. Precisa trocar o `$this` pelo `self` seja via propriedades ou método (ver exemplo)

Mude:

```
self::$instance = new PDO($this->getDBType().":host=".$this->getHost().";port=".$this->getPort().";dbname=".$this->getDB(), $this->getUser(), $this->getPassword());
```

por:

```
self::$instance = new PDO(self::getDBType().":host=".self::getHost().";port=".self::getPort().";dbname=".self::getDB(), self::getUser(), self::getPassword());
```

Usar esse padrão de projeto para uma classe de conexão não é interessante pois caso a aplicação necessite  conectar a mais de um  banco de dados não será possível (mesmo com dados diferentes servidor, base usuário e senha ) pois já existe um objeto de conexão instanciado. Em alguns casos alguns optam pelo *pattern doubleton*, que basicamente é um <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> da classe original com os dados de conexão modificados.

**Relacionda:**

[Quando usar self vs $this em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575/91)

[Singleton ou classe e membros estaticos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25306/91)

[Padrão Singleton para comunicação com banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118585/91)

[Por que não devemos usar Singleton?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18860/91)

[Devo evitar conexões permanentes e classe Singleton em um projeto PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99067/91)

Comment: Hehehe, só me dei conta agora disso. Show!! +1

Comment: Exatamente isso! Muito Obrigado.